# Which declaration of a const static object is more accurate or preferable?

Tags: c++

On the [cpprefernce website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static), a static data member was declared as:

```
class A{
     const static int k;
     //other members
};
```

In an error report while playing with `static`s the MSVC compiler report the declaration as:

```
static int const k;
```

And I just usually write it as this:

```
static const int k;
```

All of these seem to work just fine. So which of these is technically more accurate?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of opinion but I prefer the last one -- `static const int i;`.

Comment: fwiw, I definitely prefer the const to the right of what is being const-ed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it does not matter, it's a matter of code style.

`static` is a [*storage class specifier*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and is part of the declaration, it is not part of the type, so I prefer to keep it as far away from the type as possible (i.e. at far left).

Then regarding `const` - with type specifiers like `int`, `const` can be combined in any order, so `const int` and `int const` are equivalent. But `const` reads better as an adjective (*what kind of `int` is it?* it's a *`const`* `int`).

So, with all else equal, the last version in my opinion reads better:

```
static const int k;
```

Comment: Would the position of `const` depends on where you are from then if it's an adjective...? ;D

Comment: Yes I can imagine the personal preference may be affected by the author's native language. But yes, *Programmer "en français"* is a problem...

Comment: Je ne vois pas le probleme. Just joking, nice answer though I never thought of that adjective paradigm for const!

Answer (score 2):

For value types it doesn't matter.

Comment: For pointers it does.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between `const int` and `int const` as you are declaring a `const` variable on a value type.